# htaccess - Rewrite all files to index.php except sitemap.xml

Tags: php, xml, apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I am trying to redirect every php file to index.php except sitemap.xml. The problem is that sitemap.xml is redirected also to index.php. 
How to redirect all php files to index.php and sitemap.xml to sitemap.php ?

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteRule ^/?(.*)\.php$ index.php [L,QSA]
    RewriteRule sitemap.xml sitemap/sitemap.php [L]
```

Comment: Does `sitemap.xml` exist as a physical file?

Comment: No it doesn't exist. I generate it dynamically from a php file called sitemap.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an additional RewriteCond to exclude sitemap.php, otherwise when sitemap.php is requested it will fulfill the two conditions `!-d` and `-f` and will again be rewritten to index.php

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/(sitemap.php)/
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)\.php$ index.php [L,QSA]
RewriteRule sitemap.xml sitemap/sitemap.php [L]
```

Comment: If you remove the slash suffix on the _CondPattern_ then this should "work".

Answer (score 1):

`sitemap.xml` is being rewritten to `sitemap/sitemap.php`, but then the rewriting process starts over (in `.htaccess`) and `sitemap/sitemap.php` then gets rewritten to `index.php` on the second pass.

You should include an "exception" at the top of the file for any existing `.php` file that you want to allow direct access. For example:

```
RewriteRule ^(index|sitemap/sitemap)\.php$ - [L]
```

This will prevent `/index.php` and `/sitemap/sitemap.php` from being processed by the directives that follow (and being rewritten to `index.php`). `index.php` currently "works" simply because mod_rewrite later detects you are writing back to itself and ignores the second rewrite.

---

> ```
> RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\ [NC]
> RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]
> ```

*Aside:* I'm not sure what this is supposed to be doing, but I don't think this is doing what you think it's doing? In fact, I don't think this is doing *anything*!? The trailing backslash (escape char) on the *CondPattern* is the concern here. It looks like you are trying to match the *space* after the request URL (and before the protocol), but that is not what is going to happen here, at the end of the *CondPattern*. The "problem" is that the *space* is also the argument delimiter in Apache config files. In order to match a *space* at the end of the *pattern* you should either use the `\s` (any white-space character) shorthand character class, or enclose the *CondPattern* in double-quotes, or include the first few chars of the protocol (eg. `HTTP`). For example:

- `RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\s`
- `RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} "^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+) "` (escaping the space is optional if enclosed in double quotes)
- `RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\ HTTP`

The `NC` flag is mostly superfluous unless you are trying to also catch invalid requests? Any legitimate browser request will have the method and protocol all uppercase.

However, if this did match (with the trailing space) then you would get a redirect loop for any URL that did not contain a `.` (literal dot). So, either way, it does not look correct. (?)